# Why am I getting problems with my rails hash key notation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, key, notation

I have recently written some rails code lines like

```
RandomApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_ramdom_app_session'
```

and I have used this kind of code in development and in production mode - it worked properly. Now I am getting an error which I interpret I have to take the following code instead:

```
RandomApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_ramdom_app_session'
```

(Notice the different use of the hash key named 'key'.)

I was developing the application on different systems (PCs, laptops) using git. I am using ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [i386-mingw32] and Rails 3.1.3. What did change (e.g. in ruby or rails) or what did I change that made this error occur?

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't support the `{ key: value }` syntax. If it was working before then it was being run with 1.9.x at that time.

Answer (score 2):

The key: syntax is not available in Ruby 1.8.7. It was not added until 1.9. You must have changed Ruby versions somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 1):

The {key: value} is supported starting Ruby 1.9.x. The {key => value} syntax is old, but it can still be interpreted by the current version of Ruby.
Since your app was developed in Ruby version >= 1.9.x, you should not continue using Ruby 1.8.7 because then, you will encounter more strange problems moving forward.
You should check to see which Ruby version is used on production so that you can install the same version of Ruby to your system.

There is a really good Ruby Version Manager that you can utilize to switch between Ruby versions: http://beginrescueend.com/